# Selenium SendKeys to two jquery-ui datepicker textboxes intermittently does not pick up the date entered

Tags: jquery, date, selenium, textbox, datepicker

I am new to Selenium (used to do this stuff with WatiN) and I'm trying to enter a date into a textbox with SendKeys and avoid picking the date with the jquery-ui datepicker.

I have tried many things but I keep getting a problem with the date not getting picked up intermittently. It would occasionally either keep onto the original date or part of the date. i.e. change the day but not the month - This was caused by clicking the calenders day, which I'm trying to avoid.

Finally I came up with a technique that seems to work:

```
    public void EnterDate(
        FirefoxDriver driver,
        string textBoxId,
        string date)
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.Id(textBoxId)).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id(textBoxId)).SendKeys(date.Substring(0, 9));
        driver.FindElement(By.Id(textBoxId)).SendKeys(date.Substring(9));
    }
```

It seems that entering the date in 2 parts seems to avoid the issue of the datepicker messing up the date entered. First I enter all characters but the last one, then I enter the last digit of the year on it's own and by doing this it seems to give the calender time to update as text is being entered into the associated textbox.

I am wondering am I missing something here? I couldn't find the problem elsewhere after a lot of searching and it seems strange that I have to resort to this technique. Any suggestion of a different tested technique are welcome and I hope this question helps someone if an alternative doesn't exist.

**Edit:**
I looked at this issue again and couldn't figure out what was going on.
The issue still seemed to occur intermittently even with the solution I suggested above.
I think the problem is that I have 2 date pickers on my page.
The problem always seems to occur on the start date which is the first date picked and never on the second date.

I resorted to using Selenium to pick the date from the date picker to avoid the issue.
My code for that is here and seems to work without problems.

```
public static void EnterDate(
    IWebDriver driver,
    string textBoxId,
    DateTime date)
{
// Deal with the date by choosing the month, year and day from the jquery datepicker 
// Click on the date text box
driver.FindElement(By.Id(textBoxId)).Click();

// Select the month
var _selectMonth = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ui-datepicker-month")));
_selectMonth.SelectByIndex(date.Month - 1);

// Select the year
var _selectYear = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ui-datepicker-year")));
_selectYear.SelectByValue(date.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

// Select the day
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(date.Day.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).Click();
}
```

Called with:

```
// Enter start date
MyProject.Helper.Data.Entry.Form.EnterDate(this.c_driver, MyProject.Constant.StartDateId, _test.StartDate);

// Enter end date
MyProject.Helper.Data.Entry.Form.EnterDate(this.c_driver, MyProject.Constant.EndDateId, _test.EndDate);
```

I'm still interested as to why the SendKeys seems to have occasional issue when using 2 date pickers.

Comment: I am curious why you switched from Watin to Selenium? I had to switch the other way as Selenium automation was not as robust for long-term operations.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: I guess it's because WatiN has been inactive since 2011 and only supports some legacy browsers. Selenium has improved over the last three years, which is robust enough for handling most of the cases. BTW, WebDriver will be an official W3C spec.

Comment: We are on IE 9 now and will soon be moving to IE 10. The WatiN website states: "Works with Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8, 9 and FireFox 2 and 3". It seems no work has been done on this project since "WatiN 2.1 (released on 12 April 2011)" and Selenium seems to be the defacto technology for this type of testing.